# Why is for item in list not working correctly?-Please look at my simple code

Tags: python

In python, I created this simple code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 'hi', 'dog']
for item in a:
  if type(item)==str:
    a.remove(item)
print(a)
```

I want the output to be:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

But for some reason the output is showing as:

```
[1, 2, 3, 'dog']
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Don't modify a collection while also iterating over it. If you do that, you can expect unexpected behavior. Instead of modifying the original list, do it the Python way, and create a new list containing only the items you want to retain.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind creating a new list:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 'hi', 'dog']
a = [x for x in a if not isinstance(x,str)]
print(a)
```